Construction with straightedge and compass proof.
I want to prove that a certain number $\alpha$ is constructible with a compass and straightedge if and only if $\alpha$ can be written with combinations of $+, -, \cdot, \div, \sqrt{}$.
I already proved $\Leftarrow$
Now I am thinking of how to prove $\Rightarrow$
What I thought:
The only possible points we can get are of the form:
a) two lines intersecting
b)  two circles intersecting
c) a line and a circle intersecting
Let's focus on a)
We have the line equations (I couldn't draw the picture, sorry)
$y=ax+b$
and
$y=cx+d$
Subtracting the two equations, we get:
$(y = ax + b) - (y = cx + d)$
$\Rightarrow 0 = (a - c)x + (b - d)$
$\Rightarrow x = \frac{d - b}{a - c}$
$\Rightarrow y = \frac{ad - bc}{a - c}$
Great, $x$ and $y$ can be written with $-, \cdot, \div$ and coefficients $a, b, c, d$, so the new point obtained (the intersection) is written in this form.
My problem: if we guarantee that $a, b, c,$ and $d$ are written with $+, -, \cdot, \div, \sqrt{}$, then we are done. But how do we guarantee it?
One thought: for example, we know that $a$ is the slope of the line. If the line is constructible, we should have at least two constructed points from the beginning. If we have a constructed point, we can construct its $x$ and $y$ coordinates.
So, we are allowed to represent $a = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$.
But, again, we know only that $y_1, y_2, x_1, x_2$ are constructible, we don't know that they can be written with $+, -, \cdot, \div, \sqrt{}$.
When trying to prove that $\alpha$ is constructible $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha$ can be written with $+, -, \cdot, \div, \sqrt{}$, I could not do it without at some point assuming that some value $\beta$, because its constructible, can be written this way, i.e., without assuming what I am trying to prove.
Is this strategy destined to hit a dead end?

The axioms of geometry say nothing about slopes. You should not start your construction with the slope-intercept form of the equation for a line. Start with the axioms that says you can construct a line joining any two points and a circle with known center and a point on it.

Thank you very much. I will try to come up with a solution.

I could not....

Your question is not clear. The only way to guarantee that $a,b,c,d$ are constructible is either to make it part of the hypothesis or to know where they come from. If you [edit] the question to give us much more context we may be able to help. Without that we can't.
